# Local variable 'count' referenced before assignment/unsupported operand type(s)

Tags: python, variables, types, local

```
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

>>> count = 0
>>> def count():
    for i in range(1, 10):

        count = count + 1
        print(count)

>>> count()

Local variable 'count' referenced before assignment

>>> def count():
    global count
    for i in range(1, 10):

        count = count + 1
        print(count)

>>> count()


Unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'int'
```

Comment: Why do you use "count" as the name of a variable and the name of a function?

Answer (score 0):

Just a variable scoping bug, solution:

```
def count():
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,10):
        count += 1
        print (count)

count()
```

Print is fine, because count variable is scoped within count subroutine. Global would mess up the scoping (OO 'encapsulation'), as would declaring count variable outside this subroutine.

Hope that helps. IMO there's nothing wrong with a question on variable scoping as indicated by the OP here.

You could go,

```
counts = 0

def count(count):
    count = 0
    for i in range(0,10):
        count += 1
        print (count)

count(counts)
```

Comment: Still, it is never a good idea to have the same name for a variable and a function.

Comment: But certainly illustrates scoping, so in that sense I like the question. Often a variable uses the same name inside and outside scope